# Looking to add and Subtract in a IF function

Tags: c++, if-statement, math

So, Maybe I'm dumb (okay that's beside the point, cuz I am), but I'm trying to add and subtract values within a "If Statement".
So far no crashes, but it's also not adding nor subtracting...

Here's the code:

```
cout << "Let's spend some Skill Points..." << endl;
    cout << "Strength(Str):";
    cin >> UserInputSP;
    if(UserInputSP <= Player.SP && UserInputSP > 0){
        Player.Str + UserInputSP;
        Player.SP - UserInputSP;
        UserInputSP = 0;
        cout << "Skill Points: " << Player.SP << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "You don't have enough Skill Points!" << endl;
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Paste relevant code into the question.

Comment: Note: the comma operator is different from the AND `&&` operator. `if(A, B)` is the same as `if(B)`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code, these lines calculate the new values you want, but don't do anything with them.

```
Player.Str + UserInputSP;
Player.SP - UserInputSP;
```

I think what you wanted was the compound assignment operator:

```
Player.Str += UserInputSP;
Player.SP -= UserInputSP;
```

This is equivalent to saying:

```
Player.Str = Player.Str + UserInputSP;
Player.SP = Player.SP - UserInputSP;
```